# Vuex - getters value after a setter call from component

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, nuxt.js

## Scenario

I'd like to unit test my SignUp flow.

```
// pages/signup.vue
<template>
  <CustomInput v-model="inputForm" />
</template>

<script>
…
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('signup', ['input']),
    inputForm: {
      get() {
        return this.input
      },
      set(value) {
        this.setInputForm(value)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('signup', ['setInputForm'])
  }
}
</script>
```

Mu current test is in /pages/signup.spec.js

[image: Edit codesandbox-nuxt]

## Problem

`component.vm.inputForm` is not yet updated.

My question is can I mock the `action/setInputForm` that would change the value of `getters/input` without importing the store itself ?

What's the best way to test it ?

Thanks !